# Jquery/JS/CSS Hover code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Ok so heres my question:
I got the following html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="normal">Item1</li>
    <li class="normal">Item2</li>
    <li class="special">Item3</li>
    <li class="normal">Item4</li>
    <li class="normal">Item5</li>
</ul>
```

So now I want to know how to get some tricky hover effect:

- When you hover '.normal': the text colors red.
- When you hover '.normal' and 'special' is before it: '.normal' colors
  red and '.special' color green.
- When you hover '.normal' and 'special' is after it: '.normal' colors
  red and '.special' color blue.

I think this is possible with JS/Jquery but I don't know even where to start.

Thanks for any help on this question.

P.S.
For everyone who wonder where I will use this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4281191/weboutfit/index.html

Comment: you can probably do something with css only using [adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors). give this a read

Comment: @petervaz: I thought CSS didn't support back-traversal.

Comment: @jnpcl is rought. back-traversal is not yet supported, but you could make a much easier example with JQuery + CSS, posting answer in a few min

Comment: Do you only want the `.special` elements to be highlighted if they're adjacent to the `hover` element, or even if they're several elements apart?

Comment: I don't want to color all '.normal' red but only the hovered one.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pure jQuery solution for you, it implements all of your 3 requirements.

**See a working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/Rn3jR/2/

```
$(function(){
    $('.normal').hover(function(){
        $(this).css('color','red');
        var $prev=$(this).prev();
        var $next=$(this).next();
        if($prev.hasClass('special'))
            $prev.css('color','green');
        if($next.hasClass('special'))
            $next.css('color','blue');
    },function(){
        $(this).css('color','black');        
        $('.special').css('color','black');        

    });
})
```

Comment: This code seems to work perfect and is valid :D
thanks a lot!
What I like about your code is that it does prev&next at the same time ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have 3 classes namely red, blue and green (each with one color definition each).

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
.green {
    color: green;
}
```

The hover code will be like:

```
$('.normal').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('red');
    if($(this).prev().hasClass('special') {
         $(this).prev().addClass('blue');
    }
    else if($(this).next().hasClass('special') {
         $(this).next().addClass('green');
    }
}, function() {
    $('.normal').removeClass().addClass('normal');
    $('.special').removeClass().addClass('special');
});
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't work at my website :/
it even didn't went trough validation...
So I edited the code and fixed some validation things:http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/4281191/sdfhgxdhtgfchyjcyfgk.txt
but it's still not working :/

Comment: Heres a example using your code: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/4281191/test.html
As you see it doesn't work :(

Comment: I went with the code from Usman because it's a bit cleaner and it does prev&next at the same time but your code is fine too, it was great too ^^

Comment: You'll need to put this someplace such that it is executed only once the dom is ready. i.e. inside a `$(document).ready()` block. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pFPu8/ for a running demo of the code i gave. :)

Comment: Ah that explains a lot...
But I still went for above since it does teh prev and next at the same time, two if's isn't invalid right?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mQWsP/1/

```
$('.normal').hover(function () {
var that = $(this),
    special = $('.special');

that.addClass('red');

if (that.prev('li').hasClass('special')) {
    special.addClass('green');
} else {
    if (that.next('li').hasClass('special')) {
        special.addClass('blue');
    }
}   
},
function () {
    $('.special').removeClass().addClass('special');
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('normal');
});
```

Comment: This code seems to work perfect and is valid but is less clean then the code from @Usman since it render after and before not at the same time.
So I go with the code from Usman but most of the other posted answers are great too :D

Comment: if by "clean" you mean pointlessly check both prev and next, omitting curly braces, and having poor spacing, then yes, his code is "clean".

Comment: I mean by using else if instead of another if which makes the 2parts  of code run after each other instead at the same time.
And he was simply earlier too :P

Comment: the two cases are mutually exclusive and they will not run asynchronously as you seem to be suggesting. having them in an if-else-if rather than two if statements is a performance gain. but yes he was earlier :P

Answer (score 0):

I made it a bit simpler with a CSS / JS combination

CSS:

```
.normal, .special {
    color: red;
}

.special + li:hover {
    color: green;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.special').prev().hover(function() {
     $(this).css('color', 'green'); 
}, function() {
     $(this).css('color', 'red');  
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gn96t/

Comment: Instead of `.css()` you could also use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` as techfoobar did in his answer.

Comment: Hmm I tried this too but it's kinda confusing :/
And does it work in atleast IE7? since I really need it working even in that old crap browser...

Comment: What exactly? The CSS does the colorization of the element AFTER .special and the JS code the one before the .special.

Comment: I want '.special' to become green or blue depending if you hover the item before or after it and not the '.normal' element itself.

Comment: Okay, before i rewrite everything, use techfoobar's ;)